# Difference between setting a node equal to NULL vs. deleting a Node

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a node struct defined as below :

```
struct Node
{
int data;
Node* left;
Node* right;
}
```

lets say i have a node Node abc and xyz and :

```
abc->data = 1;
abc->right=NULL;
abc->left=xyz;

xyz->data =2;
xyz->right=NULL;
xyz->left=NULL;
```

Later if i want to delete the node xyz, is it the same if i say:

```
delete xyz
```

vs. saying:

```
xyz=NULL;
```

Could someone explain the difference or point me in the right direction ?

Comment: `abc->left` points to `xyx`, so `xyz->right` needs to point to `abc` instead of NULL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not the same. `delete X;` statement actually calls a destructor of the object pointed by `X` and releases/frees the memory previously allocated for that object by [operator `new`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_%28C++%29).

The `X = NULL;` statement simply assigns addres 0x0 to the pointer `X` and neither destroys the object pointed by `X` nor releases the memory as opposed to [`delete`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_%28C++%29).

Comment: So the only time I have to delete an object is if i allocated memory for it by the operator new ?..

Comment: @psj01: Correct. If you try to `delete` an object that *wasn't* allocated with `new`, bad things will happen.

Comment: C/C++ rules are simple: If you are done with memory you allocated, you are responsible for deallocating it with the corresponding function. It's also your own fault if you try to follow a wild/dangling pointer, and bad things will happen.

Answer (score 2):

`delete` frees the memory, but does not clear the pointer.

setting the `xyz` to NULL just clear the pointer, but does not free the memory.

This is one of the many differences between C++ and Java/C#/JavaScript in its memory management -- in systems with Garbage collection the clearing of a reference/pointer such as `xyz` above will allow the garbage collector to later free the memory.   C++ (or C) does not have garbage collection which is why memory must be managed as part of the program or otherwise you will end up with memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

As Vlad Lazarenko wrote above, these operations are not the same. In real code you should use smart pointers and do not call delete operator directly.

```
boost::shared_ptr<std::string> x = boost::make_shared<std::string>("hello, world!");
x->size(); // you can call methods of std::string through smart pointer
x.get(); // and you always can get raw pointer to std::string
```

Modern compilers allows you to write less code:

```
auto x = std::make_shared<std::string>("hello, world!");
```